# Mudar conteúdo de acordo com opção do select

Tags: javascript, html, select

Alguém poderia me auxiliar em como eu possa alterar as informações que estão em azul na imagem abaixo, de acordo com a seleção do select (mensal, trimestral, semestral e anual).

Eu preciso que mude o valor do produto e o link do `button`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que eu tenho é esse:

```
<select class="select-ciclos" name="select" onchange="document.getElementById('selecionado').innerHTML = '' + this.value;">   
<option value="<sup>R$</sup><span>9,99</span>/mês" selected="selected">Mensal</option>
<option value="<sup>R$</sup><span>28,77</span>">Trimestral -4%</option>  
<option value="<sup>R$</sup><span>54,14</span>">Semestral -8%</option>
<option value="<sup>R$</sup><span>99,99</span>/ano">Anual -16%</option>  
                        </select>

 <div id="selecionado" class="price"><sup>R$</sup><span>9,99</span>/mês</div>
```

Porém, dessa forma que eu tenho, ele fica apenas em uma das tabelas.

Gostaria de deixar um select único fora das tabelas para que ao selecionar, altere todas de uma vez.

Comment: usando `innerHTML` =)

Comment: Marcelo, já estou usando, porém quero um auxilio para separar um único select para todos os campos de valores.

Comment: Não está já a funcionar?

Comment: Poste seu javascript

Comment: Não tem js. Somente o onchange="document.getElementById('selecionado').innerHTML = '' + this.value;"

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mudar informações de acordo com seleção no select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218116/mudar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-acordo-com-sele%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-select)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente tente atribuir uma id para cada option, assim fica mais fácil acessá-las pelo javascript. Depois atribua Ids para os conteúdos também (por exemplo h1 id="meuh1") e deixe esses conteúdos ocultos, então tente algo assim:

```js
$"#optionID".select(function(){
  $"#meuh1".show();
  });
```

Espero que ajude...